# has_secure_password validates as "can't be blank"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having issues with password validation messages being displayed correctly. My form generates the correct error message, but it also displays a generic error which I don't need which states "Can't be blank". I can't find where this is coming from, but have seen that it might be linked to has_secure_password being included in the model?

**user.rb**

```
validates_presence_of :password, { message: "Please enter your password."}
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<% @admin.errors.messages.each do |attr, message| %>
 <li class="form-errors"><%= message.join(", ") %></li>
<% end %>
```

**Validation display message**

```
can't be blank, Please enter your password.
```

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/869a90512f36b04914d73cbf58317d953caea7c5/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb#L73-L75

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. I'm not sure how to remove the 'can't be blank' text and looking at the code, not sure how to amend this as I don't have those files.

Comment: I am having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You are probably forgetting to permit the :password and :password_confirmation parameters in the User Controller